# MYSQL Which query is faster better to use: update record from another table

Tags: mysql

Recently, I face off with updating field from another table. 
Table A is very small < 400K record. Otherwise, table B is huge > 5M record. I want to update one field from table A by using one field data from table B.

There are 2 queries:

```
UPDATE tableA AS a, tableB AS b SET a.code = b.code WHERE a.codeId = b.codeId;
```

```
UPDATE tableA a INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.code = b.code SET a.codeId = b.codeId;
```

Table B: key codeId
Table A: ref with TableB by foreign key codeId

Which query is better performance and complexity of them.

Comment: Both queries should have an identical execution plan and performance, but you should probably lean towards the join version, which is the modern syntax.

Comment: I use MYSQL 5.7, when I research this query on google, alot of answers are "join", but my table too big to join. It can run in for hours as long as my system stable.

Comment: Both queries are doing the same join.

Comment: both queries perform the same join.  When it comes to speed, try to check your indexes.